# Simple import error for numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, quandl

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import Quandl
import numpy

df = Quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
print(df.head())
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/saeed/IdeaProjects/AI/q.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\saeed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

What does this mean and how do I solve it. I'm trying to learn machine learning and I'm already running into a problem :).

Comment: Do `pip freeze` under the `scripts` folder where you have installed Python and check if `numpy` is listed

Comment: See if you get the same error if your entire script is 'import numpy'. If so, you have problems with your installation. See if there is a numpy dir inside your site-packages dir referenced in the error.